# how to change color and show tooltip when image coosen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have changed my input type file button with font awesome icon, so when I want to browse picture I can click the icon (font awesome). Now what I want is - make the icon changes into green if picture has chosen and when cursor touch it, tool-tip shows picture name/file name.

This is the script to change browse button

```
<input type="file" name="gpost" id="input"> <label for="input" id="label"><i class="fa fa-camera"></i></label>
```

---

```
input#input{
display: none;}label#label :hover{color:#53bd84;}
```

sorry for my language, i new here....

Answer (score 1):

> Use `.next` method which gives next match element of the current element. `.css` and `.attr` could be used to set the `style` and `title`  of the `element`

Try this:

```js
$('#input').on('change', function() {
  if (this.value) {
    $(this).next('label').css('color', '#53bd84');
    $(this).next('label').attr('title', this.value);
  } else {
    $(this).next('label').css('color', '');
    $(this).next('label').removeAttr('title');
  }
})
```

```css
input#input {
  display: none;
}
label#label:hover {
  color: #53bd84;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<input type="file" name="gpost" id="input" accept="image/*">
<label for="input" id="label"><i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
</label>
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/JfGVE/1061/)

Comment: Daniel Alfianto also wants to show the picture name when the icon become green.

Comment: Only suggestion I would make is add an `accept="image/*"` attribute to the input as OP *low-key* suggests `if a picture has been chosen`

Comment: thanks bro.. very much, but why it not working in my localhost? i have copy script from ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js and i copy your .attr (i dont know what is that, i just save it with .attr format). and i try to call it with this syntax below : 
<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="style/font/style/fontawesome.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="js/icon.attr" /></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
-----
i try to download it but there is not download button :(